# Lost and Found᠎

Tags: word, enigmatic-puzzle

[image]

Your final answer should find what I lost.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You have lost a:

> **[FLIP FLOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flip-flops)**!

First note that each clue:

> has *lost* 4 letters. They need to be fixed like so (spacing added):
>
>  Animal skin with h**AIR Y**ou might trade;
>  Direction of sunrise fo**R EAR**th;
>  Doneness that is by **FAR M**ore raw than well done;
>  Eye part responsible f**OR AL**lowing light in;
>  First part of a psychothera**PY RE**call aiding technique;
>  Molten rock that used to **LIE U**nderground;
>  Nazar a**MULE**ts oppose this kind of eye.
>
>  Note in all cases that the missing letters spell real words.

Now we can also see that:

> each of these corrected clues has a 4-letter answer, which we need to *find*:
>
>  Animal skin with h**AIR Y**ou might trade = **PELT**
>  Direction of sunrise fo**R EAR**th = **EAST**
>  Doneness that is by **FAR M**ore raw than well done = **RARE**
>  Eye part responsible f**OR AL**lowing light in = **IRIS**
>  First part of a [psychothera**PY RE**call aiding technique](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_recall) = **FREE**
>  Molten rock that used to **LIE U**nderground = **LAVA**
>  [Nazar a**MULE**ts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nazar_(amulet)) oppose this kind of eye = **EVIL**

Now use the diagrams. What we have here are:

> two sets of words that each comprise 7 of the 8 words needed to form a **4x4 word square**.

These can be constructed like so:

> [image: Completed word squares]

So now putting the words in green together, we know you have lost:

> a **FLIP FLOP**!

Comment: Correct! One minor detail: rot13(V unq serr nffbpvngvba va zvaq vafgrnq bs serr erpnyy), though that doesn't affect the final solution of course.